# How to schedule an action to reliably be performed once every 5 minutes?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a need for a function to run every N minutes (it doesn't need to be EXACTLY every N minutes, but it should still occur within a reasonable amount of time, maybe N+/- 5 minutes)

I've been bouncing around between the DrupalQueue class, job_scheduler, rules, actions, etc., and each time it seems like I run into a wall.

My current set up is that I use job_scheduler_trigger. I seem to have it setup correctly (using a basic UI created action of "Send email"), and I have it set to go every 5 minutes, but it NEVER fires. The "Next" run time just keeps incrementing itself properly,  but the "Last" run time is always "Never". I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, or even if this is the best way to go about it.
[image]

Comment: What kind of function is it? If it can be done through code, then you can just create a PHP file which bootstraps Drupal and performs your tasks. This then can be called from a crontab (sudo crontab -e) to run every 5 minutes :) That's provided you have shell access to your server

Comment: How do you fire your cron? Without it firing at least every 5 minutes, no Drupal system will be able to fire anything every 5 minutes. I hope you knew that already, but your question doesn't show it.

Comment: Correction: you don't need to fire cron if your solution provides something for you to fire instead, but you do need to fire *something* from the outside.

Comment: Another option is using drush and creating a custom task and then using crontab on your system.

Comment: I ended up scaling it back a bit (at least as far as the number of involved modules went.) I added a Drush command to my already-in-development module, then altered the crontab for the apache user to fire the command every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and Rules scheduler (submodule of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) seems to me "a" valid approach.

What you actually need to do is a minor variation of what is explained in the tutorial [Hourly tasks using rules scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/node/1068136): in your case you should use an offset of 5 minutes (instead of only after 1 hour). And you need to run cron every 5 minutes also (not hourly as in that tutorial).

And as explained also in that tutorial: *Initially execute the component manually* (from then on every other 5 minutes the rule will be executed again).

**Note**: [How to schedule a regular job using Rules in Drupal 7](http://yakhairsurplus.com/how-schedule-regular-job-using-rules-drupal-7/) is another tutorial that covers this topic.

Comment: This seems valid, but I went with a different approach.